# Compare many lists in Python

Tags: python, compare

I have 7 lists with IP addresses:

```py
    list_1 = ['192.168.0.1', '77.1.15.2', '30.24.15.7', '8.8.8.8', '5.6.13.8']
    list_2 = ['12.38.75.64', '30.24.15.7', '192.168.0.1']
    list_3 = ['6.15.79.64', '15.127.17.4', '192.168.0.1', '0.0.0.0', '74.58.69.14']
    list_4 = ['45.54.45.54', '89.98.89.98', '192.168.3.7', '192.168.4.12']
    list_5 = ['192.168.8.1', '192.168.0.1', '30.24.15.7', '192.168.7.24']
    list_6 = ['192.168.8.2', '192.168.8.3', '192.168.8.4', '15.127.17.4', '192.168.0.1']
    list_7 = ['192.168.0.1', '8.8.8.8']
```

How can I compare all lists and obtain the IPs that appear more than once, as well as the number of occurrences of those IPs?
IP count
192.168.0.1 = 6
30.24.15.7 = 3
8.8.8.8 = 2
15.127.17.4 = 2

Comment: Are you trying to get the count of unique occurrencies of each IP among all lists?

Comment: use `itertools.chain()` to combine multiple lists into one iterator and `collections.Counter()` to produce a dict of item:count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Counter` class to count the IPs:

```
from collections import Counter
ctr = Counter()
ctr.update(list_1)
ctr.update(list_2)
# [...] repeat for all lists

# [...] Use the counts as needed
print(ctr)
```

If you want the key/value pairs of items with more than one occurrence:

```
more_than_once = {k:v for k,v in ctr.items() if v>1}
print(more_than_once)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools` and `pandas` you could do:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

# chain all lists
l = list(itertools.chain(list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4, list_5, list_6, list_7))

# convert them to a Pandas Series and count values
counts = pd.Series(l).value_counts()

# only multiple occurrences
greaterThan1 = counts[counts>1]
```

and displaying `greaterThan1` you will get:

```
192.168.0.1    6
30.24.15.7     3
15.127.17.4    2
8.8.8.8        2
```

Comment: If you don't want to install pandas, `collections.Counter()` will produce a `dict` of item counts from a list.